# Pyspark installation

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

i am trying to install pyspark 2.4.4. The python version I am using is 3.6.12.
After I run the command

```
pip install pyspark==2.4.4
```

I got the following error

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pyspark==2.4.4 (from versions: 2.1.2, 2.1.3, 2.2.0.post0, 2.2.1, 2.2.2, 2.2.3, 2.3.0, 2.3.1, 2.3.2, 2.3.3, 2.3.4, 2.4.0, 2.4.1, 2.4.2, 2.4.3, 2.4.4, 2.4.5, 2.4.6, 2.4.7, 2.4.8, 3.0.0, 3.0.1, 3.0.2, 3.0.3, 3.1.1, 3.1.2, 3.1.3, 3.2.0, 3.2.1)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for pyspark==2.4.4
```

Does anyone know how to solve this?

Thanks

Comment: What is your pip version? Is it up to date?

Comment: it is 21.3.1. I actually can install version after 3.0.0.